# JQuery not looping through XML on IE

Tags: jquery, xml, internet-explorer

The following works fine in Chrome and Firefox but is not working in IE. It is getting data in IE (I can see it in the console)  - but it's not looping through either `.each`:

```
function searchServing(which,choice){
var url = "search.asp?" + which + "=" + choice;

$.get(url, function(data){  
    console.log("data" + data);
    $.each($(data).find("company"),function(index, el) {
        loc = $(this).find('Location').text();
        console.log("loc: "+ loc);
    });
})//$.get(url, function(data){
.error(function() {

})//.error(function() {
.success(function(data) { 
        $.each($('company',data),function(index, el) {
            loc = $(this).find('Location').text();
            console.log("location: "+ loc);
        }
    }
}
```

XML is in this format:

```
 <company>
    <sql><%=sSQL%></sql>
    <uid><%=uid%></uid>
    <companyName><%=company%></companyName>
    <location><%=location%></location>
    <phone1><%=phone1%></phone1>
    <phone2><%=phone2%></phone2>
    <phone3><%=tollfree%></phone3>
    <serving><%=serving%></serving>
</company>
```

Comment: well, why are you using each? it is a complete string with data in it!

Comment: In XML file, there are more than one company tags?

Comment: Explain the error and Add your full code bro :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be because of `console.log()`

As `IE 8` and under has no console object by default

You need to open the developer tools to make it work or create a new console object.

Comment: It's true- I am using IE 10- but I had put in  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"></meta>  .... and yet I can't remember why.... if I do i will post again. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, IE does'nt always like console.log, so remove that.

Secondly, if the tagname is in lowercase, use lowercase letters when trying to find it.

thirdly, use the `var` keyword, and don't declare variables as globals inside a loop.

Last but not least, XML should be parsed with `$.parseXML`, like so:

```
function searchServing(which, choice) {
    var url = "search.asp?" + which + "=" + choice,
        loc = []; //use array if iterating several values
    $.get(url, function(xml) {
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
            $xml = $(xmlDoc);
        $.each($xml.find("company"), function(index, el) {
            loc.push($(el).find('location').text());
        });
    });
}​
```

Comment: I would give you a check for your answer too, if I could... Lots of useful info. Much appreciated.